# 'Efficiently' fetch single value from MySQL table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I need help understanding how to “efficiently” extract one field/column/cell (that is, one piece of information) from one row of a MySQL table using Procedural Style.
The horridly long method would be something like:

```
$Qry = "SELECT Surname FROM SurnameList WHERE SID = 8 LIMIT 1";
$QryResult = mysqli_query($DBLink, $Qry);
if ($QryResult)
{
    $QryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QryResult);
    $ThisSurname = $QryRow['Surname'];
    mysqli_free_result($QryResult);
}
else 
{
   die("Transaction Failure");
}
```

Uggg.  For me, this can be compacted while still retaining readability:

```
if ($QryResult = mysqli_query($DBLink, "SELECT Surname FROM SurnameList WHERE SID = 8 LIMIT 1") {
    $QryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QryResult);
    $ThisSurname = $QryRow['Surname'];
    mysqli_free_result($QryResult);
} else die("Transaction Failure");
```

Even compacted like this, it still takes 5 lines to get one piece of information.  Isn't there a way to reduce the line count for this task within Procedural Style while retaining readability?  Some way to compact/combine lines 2 and 3?

Comment: `$QryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QryResult)['Surname'];`

Comment: Doing stuff on one line doesn't make it better or more efficient.  There's nothing wrong with the code in your first block.  It's definitely more readable than your second block.

Comment: Also, *why* are you using the "procedural style"?  What's wrong with `$DBLink->query('SELECT ...')`?

Comment: You could also abstract out the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and associated lines into their own method.  Then you could "compact" your code into `$ThisSurname = get_from_result($QryResult, 'Surname');` or something.  I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve here.  No one would call your code "horridly long" or say it really needed any improvements.

Comment: Thanks, AbraCadaver, question answered; StackOverflow is amazing!  Rocket:  Yeah, one day this old fart will try figuring out OOPS, but 'till then he'll soldier on like a creaking relic from the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is short enough that you aren't meaningfully impacting 'efficiency' at the parser. That said, you can trim a few lines by reversing your conditional to die only if the query fails (general tip, design code to avoid using else) and one-line fetching your desired result.

```
$QryResult = mysqli_query($DBLink, "SELECT Surname FROM SurnameList WHERE SID = 8 LIMIT 1");
if (!$QryResult) die("Transaction Failure"); 
$ThisSurname = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QryResult)['Surname'];
mysqli_free_result($QryResult);
```

I think you would be well served to consider classes to handle repeatable logic like this if you are after coding efficiency :).

Comment: Thanks, D Lowther; question answered.